# OOP Difference between a derived class and an inherited class?

Tags: oop, inheritance, terminology, class-hierarchy

From an OOP point of view is there any difference between a derived class and an inherited class? Or is it simply terminology?

Comment: Exact duplicate of your previous question.

Comment: @David - thanks Ok, I deleted the other question, must have submitted twice....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When using inheritance, the inherited class is called the base class, and the inheriting class is called the
derived class.

Comment: Completely changing te text of your answer to mirror another user's answer is not considered good form here on SO.

Comment: @Neil: On the contrary. Editing your answer to make it the best possible answer is what SO is all about. Of course that plagiarizing is not nice, but I find the edit an improvement based on your answer, not a blatant copy, especially since your answer was C++ specific (there was no need to make it specific, but you did.)

Comment: @Vinko There was a need need to make it specific - different languages use different nomenclatures. For example, a Smalltalk programmer would talk about superclass and subclass rather than base and derived.

Comment: @Neil: Well then, if you think so you now have an opportunity to improve your answer and make it better than the answer based on your own.

Comment: BTW, given the question, I don't think there is a need to be language specific. The question is about inherited and derived and, while some languages might out front not use those terms at all, I doubt there is any language where the terms are used and represent different things. In case such language existed, that would be a worthy addition to an answer.

Comment: I changed my answer because I realized I was wrong when I was googling a bit just to make sure I wrote a correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

The term **derived class** is preferred C++ parlance for a class that inherits from another class, which in C++ parlance is called a **base class**. So in C++ the terms you ask about are identical.

Answer (score 2):

Neil's answer confused me a bit, and so I checked some [public sources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Consider a **Base Class** and a **Sub Class** (`SubClass extends BaseClass` in Java terminology), than

- the **Sub Class** derives **Base Class** (Sub Class is a *derived class* of Base Class) and
- the **Sub Class** inherits from **Base Class** (Base Class is a/the *inherited class* of Sub Class)

So in my opinion both terms define the same relationship between to classes but from different perspectives.

Comment: The term subclass isn't commonly used in C++ - I don't know about Java - and the OP didn't ask about it.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance terminology by Bertran Meyer (Object-Oriented Software Construction, p.464):

***Basic conventions and terminology***

*The following terms will be useful in addition to “heir” and “parent”.*

*A **descendant** of a class **C** is any class that inherits directly or indirectly from
**C**, including **C** itself. (Formally: either **C** or, recursively, a descendant of an
heir of **C**.)
An **ancestor** of **C** is a class **A** such that **C** is a descendant of **A**.*

*In the literature you will also encounter the terms “subclass” and “superclass”, but
we will stay away from them because they are ambiguous; sometimes “subclass” means
heir (immediate descendant), sometimes it is used in the more general sense of proper
descendant, and it is not always clear which. In addition, we will see that the “subset”
connotation of this word is not always justified.*

Answer (score 0):

maybe interesting, if you override a method, in Delphi you write:

```
inherited; // so "inherited" is the base class
```

instead of

```
base.BaseImplementation(); // C#
```